# A light node connect to a light node or a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum

A light node connect to a light  node or a full node?

when i run geth --syncmode "light",the data is just about 40M,these data is what?just header of blocks?

Comment: i find when i run geth --syncmode "light",it takes long time to find peers,so i think it connect to other light nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A light node will connect to any node that can serve them block headers but it requests state data from nodes that have lightserve enabled. This will be full nodes since they are the nodes that can efficiently serve the merkle proofs they need.